# Accessing drop down menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav nav-pills ddmenu">
    <li class="dropdown "><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown active">
        <a href="features.html">Features</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" id="drp_pbx">Office</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="drp_call">Center</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="apis.html">API</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="downloads.html">Download</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="blogs.php">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I got to drop downs menu under 'features.html' and I wrote JQuery to display `drp_pbx` and `drp_call` drop content depend on click event

My JQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#callcenter_features").hide();

    $('#drp_pbx, #drp_call').click(function () {
        if (this.id == 'drp_pbx') {
            $("#pbx_features").show();
        }
        else if (this.id == 'drp_call') {
            $("#pbx_features").hide();
            $("#callcenter_features").show();
        }
    });
});
```

If I am at features.html table every thing works as expected, if I tried from some other pages to access `drp_pbx` and `drp_call` functionalities not working properly, even if I clicked `drp_call` it always appear content of `drp_pbx`.

I want to display content according to my click event of JQuery.

Comment: A demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker or any other javascript sandbox that replicates problem would be helpful. Also should format your code for better readability so others don't have to do it for you

Comment: yes i will follow it.thanks - @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the other menu if the second one is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#callcenter_features").hide();

  $('#drp_pbx, #drp_call').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'drp_pbx') {
        $("#callcenter_features").hide();
        $("#pbx_features").show();
    }
    else if (this.id == 'drp_call') {
        $("#pbx_features").hide();
        $("#callcenter_features").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank your for your response.even if i tried it,it gives same result.